# How to create pairs of column names based on a condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following DataFrame `df`:

```
df =
min(arc)  max(arc)  min(gbm)_p1  max(gbm)_p1
1         10        2            5
0         11        1            6
```

How can I calculate the difference between pairs of `max` and `min` columns?

Expected result:

```
diff(arc)  diff(gbm)_p1
9          3
11         5
```

I assume that `apply(lambda x: ...)` should be used to calculate the differences row-wise, but how can I create pairs of columns? In my case, I should only calculate the difference between columns that have the same name, e.g. `...(arc)` or `...(gbm)_p1`. Please notice that `min` and `max` prefixes always appear at the beginning of the column names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea is filter both `DataFrame`s by [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) with `regex` where `^` is start of string, `rename` columns, so possible subtract, because same columns names in both:

```
df1 = df.filter(regex='^min').rename(columns= lambda x: x.replace('min','diff'))
df2 = df.filter(regex='^max').rename(columns= lambda x: x.replace('max','diff'))

df = df2.sub(df1)
print (df)
   diff(arc)  diff(gbm)_p1
0          9             3
1         11             5
```

EDIT:

```
print (df)
    id  min(arc)  max(arc)  min(gbm)_p1  max(gbm)_p1
0  123         1        10            2            5
1  546         0        11            1            6

df1 = df.filter(regex='^min').rename(columns= lambda x: x.replace('min','diff'))
df2 = df.filter(regex='^max').rename(columns= lambda x: x.replace('max','diff'))

df = df[['id']].join(df2.sub(df1))
print (df)
    id  diff(arc)  diff(gbm)_p1
0  123          9             3
1  546         11             5
```

Comment: Interesting! What if I have 1 columns that should be ignored by this filtering? Let's say I have `id` that I want to maintain in a new `df`? Is it possible to do it using this approach?

Comment: @Fluxy - Give me some time